# Magento 2 Overriding or Extending Core Interfaces in custom module without use of extension attribute

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to add a new getter and setter to
**`\Magento\Catalog\Api\DataCategoryTreeInterface`**

Answer (score 0):

We cannot override Magento 2 core interfaces. So here you can use Extension Attributes for your get and set method in etc/extension_attributes.xml
And Execute : php bin/magento setup:di:compile
After that you can get method will generated under magento_root/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/CategoryTreeInterface